# Converting Date to DateTime

Tags: apex, date

Added due date on case which is a date field. Trying to get this as dateTime and here is my code:

```
case c = [select id, caseNumber, Due_Date__c, status, type from case limit 1];
Date i = (c.Due_Date__c);
system.debug(i);// returns 2015-08-07 00:00:00
DateTime t = dateTime.newInstance(i, '11:59:59');
//DateTime t = DateTime.parse(i, 11, 59, 59);
//DateTime Dt = DateTime.newInstance(i, 11, 59, 59);
system.debug(t);
```

Getting Error: "Variable does not exist: datetime"

**Update**: crmprogdev solution below works perfectly. I found another solution for the same using time.newinstance.

```
case c = [select id, due_date__c from case where due_date__C != null limit 1];               
date d = c.due_date__C;
system.debug(d);
DateTime dt = datetime.newInstance(d, Time.newInstance(23,59,59,59));
system.debug(dt);
```

Comment: You are receiving this error because you have the wrong signature for dateTime.newInstance.  See this reference.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstance_2

Comment: @Berg, Date i won't return the 11:59:59. If he wants that, he'll need to specify it when he creates the new datetime instance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the simplest method for you to use will be something like the following:

```
Integer d = Due_Date__c.day();
Integer mo = Due_Date__c.month();
Integer yr = Due_Date__c.year();

DateTime DT = DateTime.newInstance(yr, mo, d);
```

If you want to keep the 11:59:59 in your local time zone, change the last line as follows:

```
DateTime DT = DateTime.newInstance(yr, mo, d, 11, 59, 59);
```

Answer (score 25):

The most simple way to convert a date to a date time, with a time component of 00:00:00.0, is to simply assign a Date to a Datetime variable, or to cast a Date to a Datetime. For example, the following works:

```
Date today = Date.today();
Datetime todayDateTime = today; // Implicit cast
System.debug('Today is ' + todayDateTime);
System.debug('Today is also ' + (Datetime) today); // Explicit cast
```

The output would be like:

```
...|DEBUG|Today is 2017-10-18 00:00:00
...|DEBUG|Today is also 2017-10-18 00:00:00
```

I don't know which API version introduced this capability, but it is there from v39 at least.

*NOTE*: This results in a Datetime value in UTC, not in the current user's time zone.

**UPDATE**: Having experienced various issues with our managed package over the years due to such implicit (and basically invisible to the developer) conversion aligning to UTC, I can say that this approach should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for the update, potentially saving countless devs headaches.

Comment: Explicit cast worked like a charm for my case, thanks

Comment: What approach should be avoided exactly? The explicit cast looks fine to me.

Comment: The explicit cast creates a Datetime of midnight in UTC, not in the user's time zone, so you can find the date changes unexpectedly depending on the user's time zone. All the other methods work in the user's time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with Date to DateTime (and vice-versa) multiple times (just forgetting the back and forth). Here are some gists I've saved in case they help anyone else.
https://gist.github.com/cemerson/fda71148b5bbe5627a5dd6bb96164e2d