# Day calculation is not correct

Tags: apex

Why this code is not providing the exact day of the week?

```
Date d = System.today();
Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
System.debug('Day:'+dayOfWeek);
```

When I execute this, I can't get the exact day. In my system exact day is Friday, but this code returns Thursday. Anyone, please explain.

Comment: What's your timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convert a date to a datetime, the time component is `00:00:00`

When you use `Datetime.format()` on that, it's assuming that the datetime is in your (the user's) timezone and undoing the timezone offset to get back to UTC (GMT).

Thus any timezone with a "+" offset (such as IST, which is UTC +5:30) will subtract that offset from your datetime, pushing it into the previous day.

In this case, you can avoid the issue by just using `Datetime.now()` instead. It's already a datetime, so no need to convert it. You can turn your 4 lines of code into 1 (or 2 if you need to store the result in a variable to use elsewhere).

```
System.debug(Datetime.now().format('EEEE'));
```

Using `formatGMT()` or `format('EEEE', 'GMT')` instead, on your original example, would also resolve the issue (it skips the timezone manipulation), but why write more code than you have to?

Comment: Indeed. Falling into the trap of direct `Date` to `Datetime` conversion, as discussed [in this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92253/converting-date-to-datetime/196104#196104).